# How to compute a GeoJson geometry area in dart / flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, geojson, area

I'm building a flutter mobile app and I need to compute an area of some GeoJson geometries.

Say we have a GeoJson-like object:

```dart
final geo = {
    "type": "Polygon",
    "coordinates": [[
        [-122.085, 37.423],
        [-122.083, 37.423],
        [-122.083, 37.421],
        [-122.085, 37.421],
        [-122.085, 37.423]
    ]]
};
```

Assuming the projection is EPSG:4326, how do we get the actual area of the geometry using flutter or dart?

Tried to use [dart-simple-features](https://github.com/Gubaer/dart-simple-features), but this is no longer maintained and requires SDK < 2.0.0.

Another option that came to my mind is to use some JavaScript library in combination with [flutter_webview_plugin](https://github.com/fluttercommunity/flutter_webview_plugin), but oh my... That seems like an overkill!

Also there is a possibility to use [platform-specific](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-channels) code, but for the sake of development experience: let's avoid testing on multiple platforms if possible...

Any ideas? Or recommendations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the answers here are either deprecated packages or don't work. So here is a package that works with flutter 3.
package [maps_toolkit](https://pub.dev/packages/maps_toolkit)

```
import 'package:maps_toolkit/maps_toolkit.dart';

main() {

  final p1 = LatLng(45.153474463955796, 39.33852195739747);
  final p2 = LatLng(45.153474463955796, 39.33972358703614);
  final p3 = LatLng(45.15252112936569, 39.33972358703614);
  final p4 = LatLng(45.1525022138355, 39.3385460972786);

  val areaInSquareMeters = SphericalUtil.computeArea([p1, p2, p3, p4, p1]);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Okay, no reply for almost a week... Created my first dart package:

https://pub.dev/packages/area

Simple to use:

```dart
import 'package:area/area.dart';

main() {
  const world = {
    'type': 'Polygon',
    'coordinates': [
      [
        [-180, -90],
        [-180, 90],
        [180, 90],
        [180, -90],
        [-180, -90]
      ]
    ]
  };

  print("The world area is: ${area(world)} m²");
}
```

Feel free to use, hate or love ;)

Comment: I was looking for one of these in go, but I was not able to find so I did the same as you. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use [geojson_vi](https://pub.dev/packages/geojson_vi):

```dart
const world = {
  'type': 'Polygon',
  'coordinates': [
    [
      [-180, -90],
      [-180, 90],
      [180, 90],
      [180, -90],
      [-180, -90]
    ]
  ]
};
final geoJSONPolygon = GeoJSONPolygon.fromMap(world);
print(geoJSONPolygon.area);
```